# PHP namespace Error (the name is already in use)

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to run this code on the same file:

```
namespace Foo1\Bar\SubBar;

class SubBarClass {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'From Foo1';
    }

}



namespace Foo2\Bar\SubBar;

class SubBarClass {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'From Foo2';
    }

}


use Foo1\Bar\SubBar;
$foo1 = new SubBarClass;


use Foo2\Bar\SubBar;
$foo2 = new SubBarClass;
```

The ideia is to change namespaces and echo the related value.
But it's returning the following error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use Foo2\Bar\SubBar as SubBar because the name is already in use in C:\wamp\www\xxx\namespaces.php on line 30

Line 30: use Foo2\Bar\SubBar;

How can I interchange namespaces on the same file?

Thks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the last defined namespace is the one currently active.
So, when I type:

```
use Foo1\Bar\SubBar;
```

I'm still on the last defined namespace: Foo2\Bar\SubBar.
Hence, when I type:

```
use Foo2\Bar\SubBar;
```

I'm trying to use the currently active namespace. That's why the Fatal error is returned.

On possible solution is:

```
namespace Foo1\Bar\SubBar;

class SubBarClass {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'From Foo1';
    }

}



namespace Foo2\Bar\SubBar;

class SubBarClass {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'From Foo2';
    }

}


use Foo1\Bar\SubBar;
$foo1 = new SubBar\SubBarClass;


echo '<br>';
$foo2 = new SubBarClass;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) keyword is used to import that namespace to be accessed in your current file scope. It does not act as a namespace *"instance constructor"*.

You're current under `Foo2\Bar\SubBar` namespace. Like a directory of classes, while you're here, you should access other namespaces from the root (`\`):

```
$foo2 = new SubBarClass;
$foo1 = new \Foo1\Bar\SubBar\SubBarClass;
```

There is no need to use **`use`** for those namespaces (although you can, specially when they share parent namespaces), they are already declared in the same file you're using them.

For more information about this, consider reading the manual, where it describes [using multiple namespaces in the same file](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php).

Comment: Thks for the answer :)

Comment: @random425 you're welcome! If you find the answer useful for you, please consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark below the voting counter. :)